# A question about the Hebrew words translated 'righteousness' in Jeremiah 33:15/16

Tags: hebrew, jeremiah

In Jeremiah 33:15 :

> ... the Branch of righteousness [KJV]

the Hebrew word used is *tsedaqah*, so Young's Analytical Concordance informs me.

In Jeremiah 33:16 :

> ... the Lord our righteousness [KJV]

the Hebrew word *tsedeq* is that which Robert Young says is in the text.

May I ask what is the difference between these two Hebrew words ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hebrew word ṣə·ḏā·q actually occurs in three forms in Jer 33:15, 16 as follows:

1. v15a - "righteous branch", צְדָקָ֑ה (ṣə·ḏā·qāh) is Noun feminine singular, which acts as an adjective for "branch" and is obviously a Messianic prophecy.
2. v15b - "execute justice and righteousness on the earth", וּצְדָקָ֖ה (ū·ṣə·ḏā·qāh) is Conjunctive waw + Noun, feminine singular, describes the type of government of Messiah.  Apart from the conjunction "and" it is the same part of speech but now the noun is a stand-alone noun (not used as an adjective).
3. v16 - "The LORD is our righteousness", צִדְקֵֽנוּ׃ (ṣiḏ·qê·nū) is Noun, masculine singular construct, first person common plural, is used as the title of Jerusalem when it is administered by Messiah.

The flow of thought is interesting here.  Beginning with the prophesied new King, Messiah, He is given the title, "Righteous Branch"; His administration is known for its justice and righteousness; so much so that the city (Jerusalem) becomes known by the title, "The LORD is our righteousness".

Ellicott observes:

> It will be noticed that, while this reproduces the language of
>   Jeremiah 23:6, it does so with a remarkable difference. There the
>   title, "The Lord our Righteousness," is given to the future King, and
>   the passage has accordingly been used as a proof of the full divinity
>   of the Christ, who is that King. Here it is given to the city, and, so
>   given, can only mean that that name will be, as it were, the motto and
>   watchword of her being. She will be a city marked by a righteousness
>   which will be the gift of Jehovah; He will inscribe that name on her
>   banners, and. grave it on her portals. It is obvious that this throws
>   light on the meaning of the title as applied to the King.

Comment: Up-voted and accepted. Thank you. That the name 'Lord our righteousness' is also applied to the city leads my thoughts in the direction of the Revelation where the concepts 'city' and 'bride' merge into one. Thus we are become righteousness of God in Christ, in union. II Corinthians 5:21.

Comment: Yes - I agree but that was outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Outside the scope, it may be but it was edifying to have the mind drawn in that direction.

Comment: I completely agree - good comment